# Option to be selected in nested for loop in AJAX

Tags: ajax, for-loop, nested, selecteditem

Here we need to check whether the value in nested loop and the parent loop to be equal and that to be selected as well

```
for(var i = 0; i< data.com.length; i++){
    var selected = data.com[i].select_id;
    if(data.com[i].dummy != null){
        h += "<table><tr><td><input type='hidden' value='data.com[i].id'/></td><td><select>"; 
       for(var j = 0; j < data.api.length; j++){
           if( data.api[j].id == selected ){
               h += '<option selected="selected" value=""></option>';
           }else{
               h += '<option value=""></option>';
           }
       }

       h += '</select></td></table>';
   }
}
```

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: That selected thing is working fine now but Appending is not working as shown in the code. Needs to be set in different variables. And that working fine when we append to a single variable.